Is it possible to train Llama 3.1, installed locally, on text and feed it with raw text to be changed?
I have installed Llama 3.1 locally following this tutorial. I want to feed it with some PDF files and a raw file. The PDF should serve as a training model to adapt the raw text file as necessary. Do you know of any good tutorial or if this can be achieved? Given proprietary data, using online AI bots is not possible.
